# Passing @Html.DisplayFor value from main view to partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the value of  `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCost)` from my main view into partial view upon button click in main view.

```
    <table>
    <tr> 
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductCost)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCost)
             </td>
             <td>
                <input class="search" type="button" value="Select"
                    data-assigned="@item.ProductCode" />
             </td>
         </tr>
    }
</table>

<div id="MyReports"> </div>
```

And JavaScript code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('.search').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('assigned');
        var route = '@Url.Action("DisplayPartialView", "Pedigrees")?id=' + id;
        $('#MyReports').load(route);
    });
});
```

I want to get `Productcost` of that particular Id. Anyone please guide me.

Comment: Get it where? You already are passing the `id` to the method,so you can get the `ProductCost` in the method by looking it up in the database. Of you can just add another `data-` attribute in your search button - `data-cost="@item.ProductCost"` and pass it to the method if the method accepts a parameter for it.

Comment: I don't see your controller method anywhere, can you provide it? LINQ's `Where(x => x.[idproperty] == id).Select(x => x.ProductCost)` may used for retrieve data from DB. Please edit with further details about action method you have.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for giving me an idea. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ViewModel `form` with a Mvc `Ajax.BeginForm()` function to submit your datas (recommanded but need to refactore the existing code).

Or you can simply add a `data` attribute :

```
<input class="search" type="button" value="Select" data-assigned="@item.ProductCode" data-productcost="@item.ProductCost" />
```

And pass the GET parameter like `assigned` value :

```
$('.search').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('assigned');
    var cost = $(this).data('productcost');
    var route = '@Url.Action("DisplayPartialView", "Pedigrees")?id=' + id + '&cost=' + cost;
    $('#MyReports').load(route);
});
```

Don't forget to add a `cost` parameter in your `Pedigrees.DisplayPartialView(int id, string cost)` controller function.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It really worked for me.